# How to set NOT CURRENT Windows user login/pwd when connecting to MQ server?

Tags: windows, authentication, ibm-mq

(*First of all, sorry for my poor English*)

I've got MQ client (v6.0 or higher). I use mqic32.dll to connect to MQ server. I call MQCONNX to connect to the Queue Manager. MCAUser is not specified for this manager. So, I authenticated at server as a current Windows user.

Well, my program option's window has a 'Test' button and 'Login' Edit. When 'Test' pressed, I call MQCONNX - MQOPEN - MQCLOSE - MQDISQ functions sequence to test the connection/queue opening. There are 2 types of users who starts my  application - admin & operator. Admin sets options and performs connection tests, simple users sends and recieves MQ messages. They shoul log in Windows as different Windows users.

**And my question is**: 
I call MQCONNX() being logged as Admin. What parameters (among MQCD struct [sub]fields) should i set for MQ server authenticate me as Operator.

Yes, I can start new process (CreateProcessWithLogonW) as an Operator. But is there a decision keeping me in single process?

I know, using client java- libs I can specify user. So, I think, there should be equivalent ability for mqic32.dll, am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I authenticated at server as a current Windows user.

The queue manager does not authenticate an incoming connection.  It will use the UserID to check if the user can do those particular actions i.e. MQCONN, MQOPEN, MQPUT, etc.. But that is not authentication.

If you have not implemented an MQ security solution then anyone can connect with any UserID they want.

> I call MQCONNX() being logged as Admin. What parameters (among MQCD struct [sub]fields) should i set for MQ server authenticate me as Operator.

You need to create a client-side security exit and use MQCSP structure but it will not do you any good if you do not have a server-side security exit to read it.

Note: You cannot protect your queue manager from a client-side point of view because anyone can simply download one of the free MQ SupportPacs or one of the many free MQ applications and use it to connect to your queue manager.  You need an MQ security solution that is implemented at the queue manager.

Comment: Thanks, but my question is not about security or protection, we work in protected net. I have no access to server, that's why i cant add security exit. And I choose wrong term - it's not authentication. It looks like authorization, i think. As you adviced, i'll try MQCSP. Being logged as Admin, I'll set CSPUserId/Password as Operator's login/password. If MQCONNX is OK, then it's a decision.

Comment: thanks for your advice. Now I see, I can't use MQCSP having no security exits implemented. Clear MQ server ignores MQCSP. I'll try impersonation: call _LogonUser()_ (it returns impersonation token), then create test thread in suspended state, then call _SetThreadToken()_ and _ResumeThread()_. By this way Admin can test connection/opening for Operator's account. (Another way is to use java client libs, they have "impersonation" option "out of box")